# bug with wrapping angle by using wrapToPi()

Tags: matlab, angle

I found a bug in my code which affects the subsequent calculations. I have two state vectors, one for the actual robot's movement and the second one for the estimated state vector. For the robot

```
robot = [101.3203; % x
         170.6334; % y
          2.1103]; % theta in radian
```

From this position, the robot makes an observation to a beacon located at `<200,0>` (i.e. `<x,y>`). Now, the range and angle between the robot and beacon is computed as following

```
sigma_phi = (degtorad(1))/2; % noise of the angle
  sigma_r = (0.001)/2;       % noise of the range

% range with some noise from robot to beacon
qr     = sqrt((200 - robot(1))^2   + (0 - robot(2))^2) + sigma_r*randn();
% angle with some noise in radian from the robot to beacon
phi = wrapToPi(atan2(0 - robot(2), 200 - robot(1)) - robot(3) + sigma_phi*randn());
```

the angle is now `phi = 3.1285` in radian. For the estimated state vector, I have

```
Mu = [101.2143; % x
      171.0308; % y
        2.094]; % theta in radian
```

From this estimated position, the estimated state vector makes an observation to a beacon at `<200,0>` (i.e. `<x,y>`). Now, the range and angle between the estimated state vector and beacon is computed with no noise as following

```
    q = sqrt((200 - Mu(1))^2 + (0 - Mu(2))^2);
theta = wrapToPi(atan2(0 - Mu(2), 200 - Mu(1)) - Mu(3));
```

the angle is now `theta = -3.1410` in radian. My question is why `phi` is in the opposite direction of `theta` even though the robot and the estimated state vector have close values??

Answer (score 1):

You say `theta = -3.1410`, measured in radians. That's very close to -pi radians. Add a little noise to your estimation, and you can easily obtain an angle that is slightly less
than (more negative than) -pi radians.

If you give `wrapToPi` an angle slightly less than -pi radians, it will return an angle
that is slightly less than pi radians instead.

That is, as far as `wrapToPi` is concerned, there is not much difference between
your angles `phi` and `theta`.  If you compute `wrapToPi(phi - theta)`, which is what
you *should* do if you really want to know how different two directional angles are,
the result will be a relatively small number (something less than 0.02, I think).

Comment: I'm not wrapping `atan2()`, I'm wrapping the difference between the angle that I got from `atan2` and the other angle. `wrapToPi(atan2(0 - Mu(2), 200 - Mu(1)) - Mu(3))` here the other angle is 'Mu(3)'.

Comment: My mistake; I have deleted the erroneous paragraph from the "answer". I lost count of the parentheses when I was reading your code. (Such mistakes are less likely when one uses temporary variables to represent parts of complicated expressions, for example set `temp_angle = atan2(0 - Mu(2), 200 - Mu(1))` and then call `wrapToPi(temp_angle - Mu(3))` -- better still if you can think of a name that's more meaningful than `temp_angle`.)

Comment: When I use `wrapTo2Pi()`, it solved the problem however, I got another problem with same scenario but in another position. I suspect the way angles computed. According to the book I'm reading the angle should fall in `[0 2Pi]`

Comment: Different ranges of angles are good for different purposes. The range `[0 2Pi]` is good for some purposes, but for other purposes (such as the smallest turn angle that will allow the robot to face the beacon directly, or the difference between two angles), `[-Pi Pi]` is a better range. If the difference between angles is between, say, -0.01 and 0.01, the angles are almost the same. If you convert this to the range `[0 2Pi]`, the difference would either be less than 0.01 or greater than about 3.13159. Not helpful! The function `wrapToPi` returns an angle in the range `[-Pi Pi]`.